# Show specific TabBarItem after view is removed from SuperView

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

HomeViewController - View has 2 image buttons called 'New' & 'Old'. This is the starting view that I show before a TabBarController kicks into picture.

When 'New' is tapped, I go to TabBarItem 1. OK, no problem.
**When 'Old'  is tapped, I want to go to TabBarItem 4.**But it still goes to TabBarItem 1.

This is what my code looks like:

In HomeViewController, I have the following method:

```
- (void) oldButtonPressed:(id)sender{
TabBarAppDelegate *allRootValues = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
allRootValues.seeExistingClients = @"Y";
NSLog(@"old button pressed: see old clients: %@", allRootValues.seeExistingClients);

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.tabBarController  setSelectedIndex:4];
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];  
    [self.window addSubview:homeVC.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    seeExistingClients = @"N"; //Assigning to 'N' initially

    return YES;
  }
```

Comment: you shouldnt remove self from the super view, why do you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just needed to remove the HomeViewCOntroller's view so that I can see the TabBarController views. Is that the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following scenario,

```
 check the selected index which you are setting for selectedIndex:. The index for the controllers will be assigned from zero.
```

I think this may be useful to you.

Comment: Yep, I am trying to get the right selectedIndex, which is '3' i.e. the fourth tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

Dont remove self.view from the `HomeViewController`, am not sure about your view structure but i assume that `HomeViewController` is part of yout `TabBarController`

So just do the following

```
//[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.tabBarController  setSelectedIndex:3]; //3 size index starts from zero and you need the 4th controller
```

Comment: Actually, HomeViewController is not part of the TabBarController. It is a standalone ViewController which is used to present a view with 2 image buttons, before the TabBar is presented. I need to go to specific tabs when each of the buttons on HomeViewCOntroller are tapped.

Comment: nope, as i mentioned HomeBiewController is not part of my TabBar. thx fr the answer anyway. i will try something else and post it here. cheers

Answer (score 0):

youca create the tab bar controller object as follows,

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

After created the UITabBarController's object, create the references for all view controllers.example code is as follows,

```
FirstViewController *fisrtCont = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondCont = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

After creating the instances, add all the objects to array.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fisrtCont, secondCont, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = array;

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window setRootViewController:controller];

[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

Please check this, are you following all the steps? which i have followed in the above code.